# openpyxl changes number format of columns in un-altered worksheet of the same file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, datetime-format

I've noticed that when I use openpyxl to add an extra sheet to a .xlsx file, it automatically alters the number format of column(s) in a pre-existent sheet in this file.

Chronologically, the problem is as follows:

1) I use a "timestamp" format to record by hand the date and time of some events of interest in a column of this pre-existent sheet. I set, via Excel, the column format to Date (format code 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS')

[The column where I save the date and time of the events that I'm registering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRea3.png)

2) I read this "pre-existent" worksheet with pandas, and everything goes fine (i.e., pandas can read these dates/times):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(myPath + 'myFile.xlsx',sheetname='pre-existent',header=0)

print(df['timeStampUTC'])

          timeStampUTC  
0  2018-12-02 12:59:00  
1  2018-12-02 14:29:00  
2  2018-12-02 15:39:00  
3  2018-12-02 17:05:00  
4  2018-12-02 18:38:00  
5  2018-12-02 19:36:00  
6  2018-12-02 20:27:00  
7  2018-12-02 21:44:00  
8  2018-12-02 22:15:00  
9  2018-12-02 22:46:00  
10 2018-12-02 23:07:00  
11 2018-12-04 15:46:00  
12 2018-12-04 15:53:00 
Name: timeStampUTC, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

3) I do some calculations and store these other calculations at a new worksheet at the same file ('myFile.xlsx') and save the changes:

```
from openpyxl import *

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(myPath + 'myFile.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book
New_df.to_excel(writer, index = False, sheet_name='new-sheet')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

4) Once I try to repeat step 2, pandas can no longer read correctly the date-times in my column:

```
print(df['timeStampUTC'])

          timeStampUTC 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
10   NaN
11   NaN
12   NaN
Name: timeStampUTC, dtype: float64
```

It's important to notice that when I re-open 'myFile.xlsx' with Excel, the column appears as normal. When I re-set the number format of the column to Date (format code 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS'), pandas is able again to read the timestamps.

#### Anything that allows me to re-read this column with pandas is welcome.

Thanks!!!!

Juancho Gossn

Comment: Just use the utils in openpyxl to go from a worksheet to a dataframe. No need to save and reopen. It's all in the documentation.

Comment: Ok, thanks Charlie, though this is not a solution for me. Although I circumvented the problem by other means, I would really like to find out if there is a way in which openpyxl would not alter column format in the arbitrary way it currently does. Thanks!

Comment: The "column format" does not really exist. You must always format every cell.

Comment: OK, sorry, I meant cell format.

Answer (score 1):

possible partial solution:

Use read only when opening the workbook. Save the output to a new excel file.
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='name.xlsx', read_only=True)

My problem: 2 font cells change to 1 font cells.